# _ is to "momentum" as "speed" is to "velocity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Do we have a single word for the magnitude of momentum? 
If not, would there be a way to construct one from the root of the word momentum? It's not coming up in my thesaurus searches, and I've never heard of it, but I don't think it's actually that uncommon a thing to have to describe, so it seems surprising it doesn't have it's own term.

When we write it down it is "|p|", but it would be very useful to have a terse way to specify this verbally. This is often just referred to as "momentum", or if there is a need to distinguish "abs-momentum" or "magnitude of momentum", but does a single word representation exist?

Sample sentence; "The _ of the particle has a lower statistical error than its momentum."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on Physics SE.

Comment: "Momentum" has lots of metaphorical or informal uses that don't correspond exactly to the meaning in physics, and you'll find them in any dictionary. But if you're talking about statistical error it's probably better to use the correct physics terminology e.g. "magnitude of momentum". Even if a very unusual word exists with this meaning, it's still better to use language that your readers are familiar with.

Comment: I think people usually say "modulus of the momentum."  Sorry I couldn't find a single word version.  // Watch out for that nasty "it's" -- that is a contraction for "it is."  For the possessive, leave out the apostrophe.  I think that might be the most common typo in the English language!

Comment: In layman's terms (i.e., English in general), "speed" and "velocity" are two words that mean the exact same thing. Only in physics do they have differing meanings, the latter referring to *speed* and *direction*.  Moreover, momentum itself is a vector measurement in physics. If what you're looking for is a word used for momentum that is measured or quantified, that word is "momentum," and in physics, *momentum* already has direction, indicating *magnitude* (i.e., size) and *direction* (http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/mechanics/momentum/definition/momentumDefinition1.html).

Comment: @BenjaminHarman No, I'm not looking for a word for "measured momentum", I'm looking for a word for "momentum without direction information". This is something we frequently need to distinguish because one is Lorentz invariant and the other is not.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, your right modulus is a better word than abs here, abs could plausibly refer to abs(p) = [|E|, |px|, |py|, |pz|] but modulus is unambiguously |p| = sqrt(E^2 + px^2 + py^2 + pz^2). Also thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can't write an answer below now but it seems like you are looking for *[inertia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inertia)*.

Comment: @Jeeped no, unfortunately inertial would always be taken to mean "Inertial mass" which is specifically not the same as magnitude of momentum. Inertial mass is mass in in the equation F=ma (as opposed to mass in the equation F=GmM/r^2).

Comment: @Clumsycat - I didn't add an *L* to the end of *inertia*.

Comment: @Jeeped There isn't really a distinction to be had. "The principle of Inertia" is the principle that describes inertial mass.

Comment: @Clumsycat - You are so wrong on so many levels that I'm finding it hard to respond within the confines of this avenue. Good luck in your future pursuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the nearest suggestion I can find. That said, I offer it as linguistic curiosity and as illustration for just how rarefied your request is; you should not use it  in technical writing because few people will know it. Instead, you should use "magnitude of momentum" or similar phrasing that explicitly specifies what quality of momentum you want.

**[Birr](https://oed.com/view/Entry/19385)** (OED quoted; most information also in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/birr)). No, I'm not cold; this Norse-derived term originally referred to wind, but transferred to describing either *momentum* or *force*. Its imprecision (not to mention obscurity) is an argument against it:

> 2a. The force of the wind, or of any moving body; momentum, impetus; rush. to take or fetch one's birr: to gather impetus for a leap by a short run or ‘ram-race’.

...

> 2d. Bodily force exerted against anything, might.

Other words that sometimes convey *momentum* have similar issues - they are rarely used in that way or they are not specific to *magnitude* or even *momentum*. *Headway* is an example - making [headway](https://oed.com/view/Entry/84992) against a current means keeping forward speed or momentum. None of these usages entered modern scientific writing.

Finally, *moment* (a word constructed from the root of *momentum*) means too many things to refer clearly to magnitude. For instance, the *[moment of momentum](http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~hemh1/gyroscopes/momentmomentum.html)* is a vector product and should not be used to refer to magnitude alone.

Comment: I like "Birr", it's not in common use afak, so it wouldn't be confused for anything else, and it is possible to pronounce.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the overlap between the synonyms 'birr' and 'momentum' does not stretch anywhere near as far as the precise 'mass x velocity' sense of 'momentum'.

Comment: @ClumsyCat You should follow Edwin's comment. The overlap between *birr* and *momentum* is imprecise enough that you shouldn't use it or any other single-word suggestion in a technical context.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin your right, it's not something that would communicate the correct meaning to anyone else, however you may have found the closest thing that there is and it is memorable.  It will be useful for personal code-projects. That may not sound like much, but actually I write more code than anything else, and future-me is 95% of my audience.

Comment: @Lawrence that was a point in its favor! I didn't mean to dismiss it for not being in common use either, that is also an advantage in a sense because it doesn't come with existing connotations.

Answer (score 2):

In layman's terms (i.e., English in general), "speed" and "velocity" are two words that mean the exact same thing. Only in physics do they have differing meanings, the latter, "velocity," referring to *speed* and *direction.* Moreover, momentum itself is a vector measurement in physics.

If what you're looking for is a word used for momentum that is measured or quantified, that word is "momentum," and in physics, momentum already has direction, indicating *magnitude* (i.e., size) and *direction* (zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/mechanics/momentum/…).

Therefore, the proper analogy for your question would be, "*Magnitude* is to *momentum* as *speed* is to *velocity*," since *magnitude* is *momentum* without *direction*.  But, again, that's only in the technical jargon of physics.  You wouldn't be able to rely on any such nuance being inferred outside of talking to physicists or students of physics.

Comment: No, I am looking for a word that indicates the absence of directional information in the momentum value. "Magnitude" would be accurate but not precise enough in almost any context.